# how to Invoke api using simple html code?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small requirement that needs to make REST API POST call using HTML code. I have copied the sample code below and some reason this is not working. I am unable to see any call using the below code. Please let me know If there is any change required in the code.

```
<html>

  <head>

  <title>My first API script</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <H1>Testing the API call</h1>

    <form>
      <label for="msg">Message</label>

      <button id='submitButton'>Submit</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var API_URL = 'https://example.com/'; // this will be my API like https://example.com

        $('#submitButton').on('click', function(){
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: API_URL,
            data: JSON.stringfly({"message": $('#msg'.val())}),
            contentType: "application/json",

            success: function(data){
              location.reload();
            }
          })
        })

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `JSON.stringfly` should be `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Check the browser console. It should tell you about some errors you have.

Comment: JSON.stringfly is not a function. Try JSON.stringify and see if that works

Comment: Pedantic point, you can't call an API with HTML, that's why you have javascript

Comment: Also you need to update the API_URL from "example.com" to the one you want to hit the request to.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite `$('#msg'.val())` to `$('#msg').val()`, and implement an `error(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)` function in `.ajax` too so you'd catch the error next time.

Answer (score 0):

Several things need to be fixed in your code. Not sure if that's the one you're actually using but:

1. Change `stringfly` to `stringify`.
2. `label` doesn't have an `id="msg"` but you're trying to access it with `#msg`.
3. Add a `e.preventDefault()` on your click callback function. Make sure to receive `e` as parameter.
4. `label`-s don't have a `val()` function. If you're trying to get the "Message" inside the label, use `$('msg').text()`.
5. Try using API placeholders like [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) instead of example.com so you don't get CORS errors.
6. Finally, add an `error` callback to your AJAX so you can catch and handle errors.